# Android Double Value set 1.0 or 2.0, ..etc, after 0.5, 1.5, etc

Tags: android

I want to change the double value 0.5 to 1.0, 1.5 to 2.0, and so on.

I don't have any idea

```
if (overs != 0.6) {
                overs = overs + 0.1;
                txtOversMain.setText(overs + "");
                if (overs == 0.6){
                    //overs = 1.0;
                    Double ceilNum = Math.ceil(overs);
                    txtOversMain.setText(overs + "");

                }

            }
```

I want to change 1.0, 2.0, etc after every overs complete

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just store number of balls and calculate overs as

```
overs = balls/6 + 0.1*(balls%6);
```

Comment: It works fine but in 0.3 it shows 0.300000000004. Any issue?

Comment: you have come across the problems with floating point numbers. This happens because 0.1 in binary is 0.0001100110011... You can just round it off. Or, wherever you are printing it, use `String.format("%,.1f", overs);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Math.ceil():

```
Double num = 0.5;
Double ceilNum = Math.ceil(num);   // 1
```

EDIT: In your case, just use:

```
overs = Math.ceil(overs);
```

Comment: More Details please?

Comment: I applied It But now it shows results of 'math.ceil' is ignored as a warning

Comment: Check edit @BalaRaja. Let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: Check edit @BalaRaja. Nice to know that you too are a cricket fan!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit detailed answer to your issue `Math.ceil(doubleValue)` will return the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that is greater than or equal to the argument (doubleValue) and is equal to a mathematical integer.

For example:
`Math.ceil(0.5)`

O/P-1.0

For more information refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_ceil.htm)